# how to put html object element inside div

Tags: html, css, object

the html object is floating above the redbox div. How can i keep it inside the redbox div. I tried several options like reverse the divs. Somehow object is acting diverend then for example img tags. I don't know why, Search on the internet and didn't found a solution. I hope someone can help me and explain me what i'm doing wrong.

```css
.redbox{
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.42857;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 4px;
      transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
      width:25%; 
      height: 200px; 
      
}
.redbox object {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
   height:25%;
 }
 .redbox .caption {
    color: #333;
    padding: 9px;
}
```

```html
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body> 
  
  <div class="redbox">
  <object data="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html" type="application/pdf"></object>
  <div class ="caption">
  here is some text
  </div>
  </div>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: add `position:relative` to .redbox

Comment: I am not sure but do you expect like this https://jsfiddle.net/oLxjkqu2/1/

Comment: Thanks, is it that simple!. I dive deeper in position

Comment: no i was looking for the answer pete gave me. Want the object inside the div so the redbox is the mother

Comment: An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest 
ancestor whose positioning is anything other than static (the default positioning value)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use [Z-Index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) Property.

Here i am providing modified code please check it once.

```css
.redbox{
      background-color: red;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      line-height: 1.42857;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 4px;
      transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
      width:25%; 
      height: 200px; 
      z-index : 1;
}
.redbox object {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
   height:25%;
   z-index:-1;
 }
 .redbox .caption {
    color: #333;
    padding: 9px;
}
```

```html
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body> 
      
  <div class="redbox">
  <object data="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html" type="application/pdf"></object>
  <div class ="caption">
  here is some text
  </div>
  </div>
      
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what i mean was the object inside the red div and above the caption